# Dart procedural programming counting

Tags: dart, countdown, procedural

how to add 1 second delay to a loop in dart for creating count down output like this
3
'1 second delay'
2
'1 second delay'
1
'1 second delay'
0
---> Done

with procedural programming without using methods?

Comment: `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.